# Flutter FirebaseAuth error The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null' Want to get QR Code

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, qr-code

I want to create a flutter code to generate and show the QR Code. The QR Code is the current logged-in user uid from firebase. But I've got an error in firebase auth. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Hint: try `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` without `()`, this is not a function. And this is not async so you don't need `then`. The error is because `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` can be `null` in case there is no user logged in.

Comment: still got an error in documents:(

  @override

  Future<void> initState() async {    
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser ;
    
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: user!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value){
        setState((){
          imageUrl = value.documents[0].data['qrCodeUrl'];
          name = value.documents[0].data['name'];
        });
      });
    
  }

Comment: `initState` can't be `async`.  You have to use `FutureBuilder` in your `build` method to wait for the result of Firebase query using `isEqual: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, but take care of handling the case when it is `null`.